# Why is this folder hidden in Eclipse AND not hidden by a filter?

Tags: eclipse

I checked out a project someone else started. It has two folders that aren't showing up in the Project Explorer.

- They are visible in my filesystem.
- Refresh / F5 does not cause them to appear.
- Changing content in that folder and then refreshing does not cause them to appear.
- Team > Synchronize shows a change in that folder, but it's still hidden in the Project Explorer.
- *They remain hidden, even if I uncheck every box in the Filters.*
- At least one of those folders was visible a few weeks ago.
- The .project and .settings don't appear to have anything causing this.

What's going on? How do I make these folders visible? What else could I look at besides Filters? At least one of them has core project content.

Windows 7
Eclipse Kepler build

Comment: What are those folders? Are they being used for anything in particular?

Comment: "At least one of them has core project content."

Comment: We're trying to diagnose a technical problem, so the specifics matter. Can you give actual concrete details? Is it a Java Source Folder, for one? Does that content show up anywhere else?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misunderstood the intent of your question. // Neither is a Java Source Folder. FWIW, one of them is named "bin", is hidden, and I think that's desired in this case. The other is named "kfl" and was supposed to be visible. // Some searching reveals the Referenced Libraries container contains the project folder itself, for some strange reason. Inside that, "kfl" is visible. ("bin" is not.)

Does that help?